# How to access domain object I use in controller inside OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I access domain object I use in controller inside OnActionExecuting

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   // mycode executed and calling MyDomainObject ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store your object in Session or TempData and access this from the filter.